# How to use cron with mutt to schedule a basic email?

Tags: cron, mutt

I am new to both mutt and cron.  It seems that mutt and cron are both working but I can't get them to work together.

I have the following in my crontab however I am not receiving an email from it:

```
* * * * *  echo "message body" | mutt -s "Test Email" email@email.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

From the terminal I am able to use mutt to send an email using the following command:

```
echo "message body" | mutt -s "Test Email" email@email.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I can get cron to append text to a file by having the following in my crontab:

```
* * * * * echo "some text" >> /Users/me/Desktop/stuff.txt
```

EDIT:
At the top of the crontab I have put MAILTO="email@email.com"
Now each time the cron job runs I get an email from the Cron Daemon which reads:

> /bin/sh: mutt: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path value needed to be set in the crontab:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin"
```